# Printing without UIPrintInteractionController

Tags: objective-c, printing

i am developing a POS(point of sale)application.i am able to print successfully with the UIPrintInteractionController popover. however , when a printticket button is pressed on the screen it should directly print without having the print interaction popover. i am not sure if this can be possible.

can anyone suggest an alternative?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've interacted with the iOS Printing API a bit, and I've never come across a way to print without using the `UIPrintInteractionController`.  As an iOS device user, I'm not sure I'd *want* a way to print without my say-so, because then any old app could just start spamming my printer.

Comment: my app is a POS(point of sale) App. i would be printing  tickets every 20-40 seconds or so. so a popover every 20 seconds giving me an option to choose printer would not be ideal. i would like to setup the printer once when the app starts and keep printing to that printer until i quit the app.

Comment: @Rajashekar I understand that there are specific motivations for wanting it that aren't nefarious, but there are *so*  many ways an API like that could be abused. For example, you may want to write an app that lets you send a text message without telling the user, but what if someone wrote an app that started spamming your contacts with messages, each one charging you money? The same goes for printing.

Comment: @Rajashekar as always, however, things can change.  If this is something that you'd like to have, please request it:  http://bugreport.apple.com .  Give a good use case, etc, and your request *will* be seriously considered.

Comment: @Rajashekar Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar need to you and would like to avoid that popover.

Comment: @Rajashekar I'm with the same problem too, any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Good news, with iOS8 it is now possible to print without UIPrintInteractionController. See the WWDC 2014 video [Adopting AirPrint](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=718). They specifically mention how useful this is for POS applications.

Comment: could you please expand your answer a little more? Thank you